# Barcode in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, fonts, barcode

I am preparing an application for a pharmacy using excel, I need some kind of method by which I can generate barcodes which can be readable by barcode scanner

following is a example which convert a number to barcode of Code128 symbology.
[image: conversion of number (10019) to barcode]

Comment: Glad to see the font and UDF worked out for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solid tutorial about creating barcodes in Excel http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Barcode

I have never used it personally, but if you look at step 4 it walks you through the process of installing a .bas file into the Excel VBA editor, they call it `"=Code128()"`which allows you to use a custom User Defined Function that will generate the bar code. This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks I am already working on it I found this method by googled.

Comment: Also it's important to note that the link I provided will provide you with a free copy of the bar code font that `Shane Wealti` mentioned in his answer. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be way too simple, however here's an idea:

Using the pipe and space characters combined with the font 'Hattenschweilier' blocks can be generated from binary strings using the following method (note cells on the left contain the output of cells on the right):

[image: barcode from value]

I don't have any experience working with barcodes, hence the control characters at each end (101) to locate the start and finish. These would need to be removed to recover the original value.

Regards,

James

Comment: did you test this method with barcode scanner? as this is not working for me. This is really very interesting if it worked...

Comment: Unfortunately not as I don't have such a device. If you do then I'd think the best way forward would be to print some values and test them. Basically this gets you from a binary value to a printable code that consists of vertical bars of white and black colour and equal widths, although I haven't gone any further.

Comment: Could you post back a sample value and required barcode? I can take a further look with this information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of bar code you need to generate but the easiest way is to purchase or otherwise acquire a bar code font (for the particular encoding you need). Then it is as simple as filling the cell with the data and formatting the cell with the correct font.